# Raising of the sparks

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism

Central in the chassidic philosophy is the concept of the raising of the sparks of holiness to the realm of Atzilut. For Source, see for example this:

"It is part of the spiritual structure of the universe that fragments or "sparks" of G‑dliness (so to speak) are embodied within the substance of the physical world, and it is our task to elevate these sparks back to their heavenly source by utilizing material things for holy purposes. When we do this, the sparks of holiness are raised up to the spiritual level known as malchut of Atzilut, which is the limit of human capability. However, once we have done all we can on our part, the sparks are drawn from there even higher by a still loftier spiritual level."

(Source: http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/379962/jewish/Count-and-Wave.htm)

When I read this I also compare this to the idea of "dira ba tachtonim", that the Whole purpose of the creation of the world was to create a home for g-d, a dwelling Place between the emanations.

Question:

If the mission of raising the sparks is to raise the sparks of holiness OUT of this physical world (The world of assiyah), how does this then relate to the Central idea of that the Whole purpose of life is to create a home for G-d in this physical world?

Answer (score 2):

The goal is that the physical world will shine of the glory of the Shechina. ומלאה הארץ דעה את ה, that the whole earth will be full of knowledge of Hashem. This is connected to ביום ההוא יהיה ה' אחד ושמו אחד, that He will be one and His name will be one.

What we aren't hoping for is that the divine should become physical but rather that the physical world will be strongly connected to, and fully in sync with, the divine.

The concept of these "sparks" is that there are holy aspects which were disconnected and downgraded. Specific ideas which are not being utilized for holiness and exist in the realm of chaos. Elevating them means to put them back in their rightful position, as part of the system of holiness.

Once this is done they can truly shine from their place onto this world.