# Lifting up the holy sparks - The Ari on Mitzrayim

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, mysticism-kabbalah, yetziat-mitzrayim, arizal

Lifting up the holy sparks is also known as *nitzotzos dikedushah* [(see footnote 10](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/96072/jewish/Lag-BaOmer-Sharing-the-Inner-Core-of-the-Torah.htm#footnoteRef10a96072), see also [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/60907/27180)). I recently saw [this article](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/promotions/2163138/the-last-two-weeks-of-shovovim-are-here-submit-your-names-and-reb-gamliel-shlita-will-daven-for-you-and-your-family.html) quoting the Ari HaKodesh in saying that the work the Jewish People did in Mitzrayim, was in order to lift up the sparks that were scattered after the sin of Adam HaRishon, in order to purify them and put them into the right (holy) place.

The Ari is quoted [saying](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/promotions/2163138/the-last-two-weeks-of-shovovim-are-here-submit-your-names-and-reb-gamliel-shlita-will-daven-for-you-and-your-family.html#:%7E:text=The%20Ari%20HaKadosh%20explains,by%20Torah%20and%20Avodah.):

> The Ari HaKadosh explains that when the Yidden were in Mitzrayim, the
> hard work was in order to lift up all Nitzotzos Hakedushah (- holy
> sparks, so to speak) that fell in wrong places after the sin of Adam
> Harishon. Through the hard work and suffering they lifted up most of
> it. We still need work on the rest of the Nitzotzos and when they are
> all completely restored, Mashiach will come.
>
> The Levi’im who didn’t work hard, did the work of lifting the
> Nitzotzos by Torah and Avodah.

**1.  Where does the Ari HaKadosh say this (translation is very welcome)?** and does the Ari give an explanation on what this exactly means, that "the hard work was in order to lift up all the Nitzotzos HaKedushah"?

Comment: The relationship of Levi with the rest of Israel is similar to the relationship of the Tzaddik to the Benonim/Rashaim of Tanya (see this answer for a bit of an explanation: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/132008/31534). The word "sparks" may be Lurianic, but the general idea is rooted in all of Torah, that we are here to elevate the world. Does that make sense, or if not could you clarify your question a little?

Comment: Thanks. The Tiferes Yehonasan, Parashas Vaeira explains that Shevet Levi was excluded from slavery because paraoh knew that from that tribe, the future redeemer would come. So the base that Levi'im did not work is known to me. However, is it also a common idea that instead of working, Levi'im were studying and teaching Torah?

Comment: From the article I quoted there: "They would then remain the root of Bnei Yisroel to ensure the survival of what characterized Bnei Yisroel. The “work” of the Levites during the enslavement was the study of Torah. When their census was taken in the desert, they numbered 22,000, to mirror the twenty-two letters of the aleph bet through which the Torah is written, writes the Be’er Moshe, the Ozhorover Rebbe.". Bli neder I'll see if I can find more sources, but anecdotally I've heard this in many contexts, not just kabbalah

Comment: Great source. Ty!

Comment: I think the most common source of what you are quoting is the Shelah.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE where can the Shelah be found? Besides that, I am also looking for where this Arizal can be found.

Comment: Ari - שער הגילגולים הקדמה ט"ו

Comment: @TheGRAPKE if you want, this could be an answer provided it translates the piece I was looking for. I haven't found it yet.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE I have had a look, he doesn't mention Mitzrayim there

Comment: @RabbiKaii Sorry, I must have been quoting an incorrect reference.