# Avraham going down to Mitzrayim: contradiction between the Satmar Rav and Noam Elimelech

Tags: commentaries, chasidut-hasidism, vayera, satmar, noam-elimelech

The Noam Elimelech teaches us that Avraham Avinu went down to Mitzrayim to "influence" the wicked in his generation. In order to do this, a tzaddik sometimes needs to "descend to a lower level than his own" [(Noam Elimelech, Parshas Toldos 5)](https://www.sefaria.org/Noam_Elimelech%2C_Sefer_Bereshit%2C_Toldot.5.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> אך הענין הוא, דהנה כשיש רשעים בדור שהם מעכבים ההשפעות, אזי הצדיק הרוצה להשפיע לעולם צריך לירד ממדריגתו עד סוף מדריגתו תחתונה ע"ד שאמר הכתוב ממעמקים קראתיך, ולכן בימי אברהם שהיה דורו רשעים והיה צריך לירד ממדריגתו לגמרי, לכן הוכרח לירד מצרימה ששם הוא מקום עב ומגושם ביותר כדי שיטה עצמו גם הוא ממדריגתו העליונה, שיהא יוכל להשפיע ע"י תפילתו, תפילה לעני כו', דהמתפלל צריך להיות כעני עומד על הפתח, אבל יצחק הגם שהיה דורו רשעים לא היה צריך לירד מצרימה כדי לגשם עצמו, דהנה ידוע דאותו דבר אשר כבר תיקן איזה צדיק בתפילתו, אזי אח"כ אם יארע לצדיק שיהיה אחריו ג"כ אותו הדבר, בקל הוא לו לפעול הדבר הזה מחמת שכבר תיקן הצדיק הקודם לו, ולטעם הזה אמר הכתוב "מלבד הרעב הראשון", כדי לתת טעם לזה שלא היה צריך יצחק לירד מצרים. וק"ל.

Refer to the section "sources" in the Peer Mikdoshim-version of the Noam Elimelech, where it says this idea (p. 84). See also [my question here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/133141/27180) on "raising the sparks". Refer also the ["Or Torah" by the Maggid of Mezritch (Parashas Vayeishev)](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/14359/p/29/t/0.84092812602724171234/fs/KOd0rOlWDSuNbIotR03UORQapabLIXX8BK5mU1Tesy78/start/2148/end/2155/c).

With the holiness of the tzadik, the "light of the Tzadik" as the Noam Elimelech calls it [(Toldos 6)](https://www.sefaria.org/Noam_Elimelech%2C_Sefer_Bereshit%2C_Toldot.6.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), he can influence the wicked.

> ויזרע יצחק בארץ ההיא כו'. דהנה דוד המלך ע"ה אמר "אור זרוע לצדיק כו'", יש לפרש דאור הוא זרוע אצל הצדיק, דהיינו הקדושה והאור שבו הוא כמו זריעה שעושה פירות, שהוא גורם בקדושתו התעוררות יראה על כל העולם וזורע בבני אדם האור הקדושה, "ולישרי לב שמחה" ר"ל ואותם שאינם רק ישרי לב, יש להם מדרגת שמחה, דהיינו שבני אדם שמחים עמהם בראותם אותם, אבל אינם יכולים להזריע אורות קדושות באחרים. וזהו "ויזרע יצחק בארץ ההיא" כנ"ל, שהזריע בבני אדם יראה וקדושה, "וימצא בשנה ההיא מאה שערים", דחייב אדם לברך מאה ברכות בכל יום. והם נתקנו נגד מאה נפשות שהיו מתים בכל יום ותיקן דוד המלך ע"ה נגדם מאה ברכות, והצדיק הזה המזריע קדושה ויראה בבני אדם הרי הוא כאילו מחיה אותם, ועל ידי זה הוא גורם תיקון למאה שערים הידועים, כי לכל איש ואיש יש שער מיוחד לו, והמקיימו הוא מתקן אותו השער המיוחד.

However, this got me thinking of something I rembembered reading. The Satmar Rav in his [Chiddushei Torah (תשט"ז 1956) on parshas Chayei Sarah](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/641603/p/70/t/0.82883384917911811234/fs/oyYY1zUkeOvlQEHerFCfphLFk74oizNNEmovnvw0tcbp/start/18/end/42/c) explains that although Avraham Avinu prayed for the people of Sodom and Gomorrah, he never wanted to associate with them. Why not? Because one should not associate with the wicked.

Avraham Avinu wanted to bring people closer to G-d and His Torah, as is said in [Avos D'Rabi Noson (12:8)](https://www.sefaria.org/Avot_D%27Rabbi_Natan.12.8?ven=Avot_DeRabbi_Natan,_trans._by_David_Kasher,_2019&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> And bring them closer to Torah. How so? This teaches us that a person should prevail upon others and bring them under the wings of the Divine Presence, just as Abraham prevailed upon those around him and brought them under the wings of the Divine Presence.

I found a wonderful [Ohev Yisroel (Parshas Toldos, sv. אלה תולדות יצחק בן אברהם גו')](https://www.sefaria.org/Ohev_Yisrael%2C_Toldot.1.1?lang=bi&lookup=%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7%20%D7%91%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%92%D7%95%27.%20%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%99%20%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%94%22%D7%A7%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%93%D7%97%D7%96%22%D7%9C%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%20%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%AA%20%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%AA%20%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%90%D7%94%D7%91%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%20%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%91%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%A9%22%D7%99%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9C%20%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93%20%D7%A2%D7%9D%20%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%95%22%D7%90%20%D7%91%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95.%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F.%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97%20%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93%20%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D.%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7%20%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%94%20%D7%A4%D7%97%D7%93%20%D7%95%D7%92%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A2%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%9D%20%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%99%D7%AA%27%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%AA%27%20%D7%A2%22%D7%99%20%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A9%20%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A9%20%D7%93%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%97%D7%95%D7%93%20%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%99%D7%AA%27%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%A9%20%D7%97%22%D7%95%20%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%90%20%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D%20%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D%20%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%9F%20%D7%95%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%20%D7%A9%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%94%22%D7%A7%20%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7%20%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%A2%22%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7%20%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%20%D7%90%D7%A3%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%20%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A%20%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A2%20%D7%91%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99.%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9A%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A8%20%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%A2%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A%20%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%95.%20%D7%90%D7%9A%20%D7%9B%22%D7%96%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%97%D7%93%20%D7%95%D7%92%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A7%D7%94.%20%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9C%20%D7%91%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%AA%20%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7%20%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%95%20%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%9A%20%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%94%20%D7%96%D7%95%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA.%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%94%20%D7%96%D7%95%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%A8%D7%A7%20%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%95%D7%92%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%96%D7%A9%D7%94%22%D7%9B%20%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%A8%D7%91%20%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91%D7%9A%20%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%20%D7%A6%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%AA%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9A%20%D7%A8%22%D7%9C%20%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%AA%20%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%99%D7%90%20%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%27%20%D7%A6%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%9C%D7%A6%D7%93%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%94%20%D7%96%D7%95%20%D7%A2%D7%A6%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%A6%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%95%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%96%20%D7%95%D7%98%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%A8%D7%91%20%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91%20%D7%95%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93.%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%AA%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%96%D7%94%D7%91%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%20%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D%20%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A8%20%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%A1%D7%A3%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%A1%D7%A3%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%27%20%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93.%20%D7%95%D7%92%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%9F.%20%D7%95%D7%96%D7%94%D7%91%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%27%20%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%98%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%90%D7%A2%22%D7%9B%20%D7%95%D7%95%D7%93%D7%90%D7%99%20%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9A%20%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%27%20%D7%94%D7%96%D7%94%D7%91%20%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%96%20%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D.%20%D7%90%D7%9A%20%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%96%D7%94%D7%91%20%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%27%20%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%A7%27%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%90%20%D7%93%D7%93%D7%94%D7%91%D7%90.%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%9B%D7%A2%D7%AA%20%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9B%D7%97%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%A7%20%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%94%20%D7%96%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9A%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%A2%20%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%A6%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%91%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%AA%20%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A2%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%98%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%92%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D%20%D7%97%22%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%9F%20%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9A%20%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%A2%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A9%20%D7%A8%D7%A7%20%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%98%20%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%27%20%D7%A2%D7%93%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%97%20%D7%A6%D7%93%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%91%22%D7%90.%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%96%20%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%A7%20%D7%94%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%20%D7%99%D7%AA%27%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%20%D7%94%D7%A9%22%D7%99%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A5%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%95%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%92%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%97%D7%93%D7%95%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA.%20%D7%90%D7%9A%20%D7%9C%D7%A2%22%D7%A2%20%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9A%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%94%20%D7%96%D7%95.%20%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%A9%22%D7%99%20%D7%96%22%D7%9C%20%D7%A2%22%D7%A4%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9D%20%D7%9B%D7%95%27%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5%20%D7%A9%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%A8%20%D7%94%22%D7%A4%20%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%91%22%D7%A8%20%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%95%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%91%22%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%A6%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%A2%22%D7%9C%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A3%20%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%90%20%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%92%22%D7%9B%20%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A2%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%20%D7%9B%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%27%20%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%A2%D7%93%20%D7%A2%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9C%27%20%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%99%27%20%D7%94%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%9A%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%99%27%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%91%22%D7%94%20%D7%97%D7%9E%27%20%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%A8%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A7%27.%20%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9C%20%D7%91%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%AA%20%D7%92%D7%9D%20%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9C%20%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A9%20%D7%94%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D7%90%D7%A2%22%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93%20%D7%A0%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9C%20%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%A0%22%D7%9C.%20%D7%95%D7%96%D7%A9%22%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7.%20%D7%A8%22%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%97%20%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%20%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%AA%20%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7%20%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%A9%20%D7%91%D7%94%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%91%D7%90%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%97%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%91%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%91%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%AA%20%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93.%20%D7%95%D7%96%22%D7%A9%20%D7%91%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%97%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%91%20%D7%A0%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9C%20%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%97%20%D7%94%D7%91%D7%9F%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%91%D7%9F.%20%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%A4%22%D7%96%20%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A8%20%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%90%D7%95%20%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7%20%D7%92%D7%95%27%20%D7%94%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8%20%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%20%D7%97%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%95%20%D7%92%D7%95%27.%20%D7%93%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%20%D7%99%D7%AA%27%20%D7%94%D7%98%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2%20%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%A0%22%D7%99%20%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9C%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%98%20%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%95%22%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%94%D7%90%20%D7%91%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A2%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%20%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%A8%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D.%20%D7%90%D7%9A%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8%20%D7%95%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%9B%D7%91%20%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%95.%20%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9A%20%D7%9B%22%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A8%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9D%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95.%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A9%20%D7%A6%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A7%20%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%A9%22%D7%99%20%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%92%20%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%A2%22%D7%99%20%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%20%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%97%20%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A7%20%D7%90%22%D7%A2%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A9%22%D7%99.%20%D7%90%D7%9A%20%D7%99%D7%A9%20%D7%91%22%D7%90%20%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A9%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%95.%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%96%20%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9A%20%D7%94%D7%A9%22%D7%99%20%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9C%20%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%91%D7%91%20%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%9C%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%A2%22%D7%99%20%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%9B%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A8%20%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%9A%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9A%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9C%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%96%20%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%A8%22%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%22%D7%A0%20%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%AA%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%A2%22%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%AA.%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%27%20%D7%96%D7%95%20%D7%A0%D7%A7%27%20%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%A9%22%D7%99%20%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%91%D7%91%20%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%9C%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D%20%D7%9B%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F.%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%96%20%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A8%20%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%A7%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%A0%22%D7%9C%20%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A0%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9F%20%D7%95%D7%A2%22%D7%99%20%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%A9%22%D7%99.%20%D7%95%D7%96%22%D7%A9%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%90%D7%95%20%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7%20%D7%A8%22%D7%9C%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%97%D7%99%20%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%94%22%D7%93%20%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9F%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F.%20%D7%90%D7%96%20%D7%A0%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%9B%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D.%20%D7%95%D7%96%22%D7%A9%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%92%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%95.%20%D7%A2%22%D7%93%20%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%93%20%D7%AA%D7%91%D7%95%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A9%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A7.%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%A0%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%95%20%D7%A2%D7%99%22%D7%96%20%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%95%20%D7%94%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%95%22%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97%20%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9C%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A5%20%D7%91%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%22%D7%A0%20%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA.%20%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9B%D7%9F%20%D7%99%D7%94%D7%99%20%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%9F%3A&with=Lexicon&lang2=en) where it says that a tzadik can bring forth the light of Torah in a "dark generation" so to speak. He can uncover that light whenever that light is "clogged up" by darkness.

The Avos D'Rabbi Noson seems to be in line with what the Noam Elimelech teaches us. However, the Satmar Rav is saying something else. The Noam Elimelech is saying that in a wicked generation, a tzadik needs to descent in his own level, in order to "go down" and influence the wicked to do good and turn to G-d. However, why didn't he do that with the people of Sodom? Why didn't he try to influence them in light of this Noam Elimelech (besides the obvious reasons ofcourse).

Comment: From a practical perspective, Avraham could feasibly impact on the people of Sodom as they didn't let guests in. So he didn't really have an opportunity...

Comment: That seems obvious but thanks. That can fall under the principle of midas s'dom. But Avraham could've tried.

Comment: Maybe there are sources that explain why? :)

Comment: I would guess that it's because he agreed with Lot that he wouldn't barge in on his territory. Lot chose the area of Sdom as his territory, so Avraham didn't come near, except when Lot was in danger. On a daily basis he wouldn't have been able to go to Sdom to try to influence the people there.

Comment: The [Chizkuni](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.13.12?lang=bi&with=Chizkuni&lang2=en) says that Lot did not take residence inside Sodom itself. But the question requires something "deeper". How great would it be to influence people like those from Sodom to come closer to Hashem, to return and to abandon their bad ways.

Comment: (If you don't tag me I won't know that you've replied to me). I believe Rashi also states that he gradually moved closer to Sodom. That the 4 kings captured Lot as well appears to suggest that he was considered very much part of the Sodomian region. If your question is not why Avraham didn't do X but rather how much would it take to do X, you should clarify that.

Comment: כל היכא דהוה מחי ר' אלעזר הוה מסי ר"ש

Comment: @Harel13 No, I am looking for reasons why Avraham did not even try to influence them. He prayed for them, but that's it.