# Transferring Holy Sparks

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

In Kaballah, there is the idea that we lift holy Sparks back to their source by utilizing the material world in the way, G-d wants it to be utilized. I have heard that holy sparks can also be transferred from Person A to Person B by e.g., one Person causing the second to suffer. Or by Person A giving Zdakah to Person B.

Can someone give me a source for this concept, further reading material or an explanation?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: If Person A is *mechabed* (honours) Person B more than Person B is actually capable of honouring themselves then *nitzotzos ha'kedushah* (holy sparks) of B are given to A but B does not loose out.

Comment: Relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/133141/27180 & https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60897/27180

Comment: The best sparks is Nanach. Saying Nanach and publicizing this holy name every where at all times according to Sabba. Neither A the Nanach sayer nor B the Nanach hearer, etc., neither lose and they're aderaba not harmed or jealous of by the mazikin or Any haRa or the David because Nanach runs away from Kavod. When Kavod comes to a man he needs to be very careful bc it's the Em Kol Chai and may be coming to take him home. This is in L. Moharan, idk which Torah but search כבוד.

Answer (score 0):

Actually found an answer in Likkutei Halachot. He speaks about sacrafices which benefit the nations actually extracting sparks from the Nations. Maybe can be extracted to Tfillot etc.:

(Likutei Halakhot, Orach Chaim, Laws of the New Year 4:8:1)

וְזֶה בְּחִינַת מַה שֶּׁאָמְרוּ רַבּוֹתֵינוּ זַ"ל (זהר רע"מ פינחס רנו. רש"י במדבר כט), שֶׁמִּתְמַעֲטִין וְהוֹלְכִין כְּפָרֵי הֶחָג, כִּי בָּזֶה שֶׁאָנוּ מַקְרִיבִין עֲלֵיהֶם שִׁבְעִים פָּרִים כְּדֵי שֶׁיִּהְיֶה לָהֶם אֵיזֶה קִיּוּם בֶּאֱמֶת זֶהוּ מַפַּלְתָּם, בִּבְחִינַת אִם רָעֵב שֹׂנַאֲךָ הַאֲכִילֵהוּ לֶחֶם וְכוּ' כִּי גֶּחָלִים אַתָּה חוֹתֶה עַל רֹאשׁוֹ (משלי כ״ה:כ״א), כִּי עַל-יְדֵי זֶה הֵם כָּלִים וְהוֹלְכִים, כָּלִים וְהוֹלְכִים לְגַמְרֵי, וְזֶהוּ שֶׁמִּתְמַעֲטִים וְהוֹלְכִים כְּפָרֵי הֶחָג, כִּי דַּיְקָא עַל-יְדֵי פָּרֵי הֶחָג שֶׁמְקַיְּמִים אוֹתָם, עַל-יְדֵי זֶה מְבָרְרִים הַקְּדֻשָּׁה מֵהֶם בְּכָל פַּעַם. וְזֶהוּ עִקַּר מַפָּלָתָם וְזֶהוּ מַמָּשׁ בְּחִינַת וְנָפִיק הַנַּ"ל שֶׁמְּבָרְרִין הַקְּדֻשָּׁה מִמְּקוֹמוֹת הַחִיצוֹנִים כַּנַּ"ל וְאָז יִשְׂרָאֵל לְמַעְלָה מִכָּל הָאֻמּוֹת

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something similar..

When the Kavod comes to a man, for example he is given more prestige, honor or money -- he needs to be very careful bc Kavod is the Em Kol Chai and may be coming to take him home. This is in L. Moharan, idk which Torah but search כבוד.