Earliest textual source for the concept of Holy Sparks?
What is the earliest known/cited textual source for the concept of holy sparks?

Could you be specific? Do you mean the Arizal's concept? There are also very different ideas referred to as sparks in prophets and geonim.

I'll leave it up to the answerer as I am less knowledgable and not sure.

possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/135466/759
